# Access Unity variables in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Is it possible to access variables (for example a highscore) from a unity game in eclipse?
The variables are stored in unity scripts like this:

```
using Assets.Scripts.Events;
using Assets.Scripts.Utils;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
public class ScoreManager : CommandMonoBehaviour
{
    public int Score;

    public void Start()
    {
        Subscribe(GameEvents.BasketGotMovingObject, OnBasketGotMovingObject);
    }

    private void OnBasketGotMovingObject(GameEventArgs<MovingObject> args)
    {
        Score = Mathf.Max(0, Score + args.Value.BonusPoints);
        GameEvents.ScoreUpdated.Publish(new GameEventArgs<int>(Score));
    }
}
}
```

The project has been exported to a "Google Android Project" through the Unity IDE.

The onCreate Function in the exported project looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().takeSurface(null);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
            getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

        View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
        setContentView(playerView);
        playerView.requestFocus();
    }
```

There is only a "UnityPlayer".
How can i access the scripts variables like "int Score"?

Comment: The tag unity is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have opened the solution in eclipse, make sure you get the component of the game object the script is attached to. You could use

```
var scoreManager = GameObject.FindOnbjectOfType(typeof(ScoreManager)) as ScoreManager;
```

If you don't know the object to which the ScoreManager script belongs to. If you do know the object to which te script belongs to you could use the following (replace obj with the actual name)

```
var scoreManager = obj.GetComponent<ScoreManager>():
```

And from there you could do

```
scoreManager.Score
```

I am also assuming the class you are deriving ScoreManager from at some point derives from MonoBehaviour which is the required class to attach scripts to game objects in the scene.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but that's not possible. You could however use plain java code in unity by creating a plugin. You would not be able to access any of Unity's libraries though. To create a plugin in java you could use this answer as a guide http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15308/can-i-access-java-code-from-unity.html

Comment: A plugin is basically precompiled code (with .dll extension). the dll file has to go in a Plugins folder created inside the Assets folder. The folders has to be named "Plugins" and be located directly in the Assets folder. To convert a .jar file which is a file containing compiled java code into a .dll which is needed for Unity to understand the plugin, please follow the above link, but for cresting a Unity game entirely in Java, I'm afraid that's not possible. Hope this helps